# How I do manually change the key labels values in a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I wonder how I can change the key labels in the legend box. I need replace the values 1 by the word " Activo" and the values 2 by the world "Inactivo" I tried to use `scale_fill_discrete` but It does not work

This is a sample of the data frame

```
 structure(list(ZPIE = c(4109L, 4463L, 4624L, 4267L, 4569L, 4656L, 
3976L, 4136L, 4139L, 4694L, 4354L, 4615L, 4183L, 4113L, 4508L, 
4035L, 4443L, 4709L, 4575L, 4363L), ecd = c(0.0873015873015873, 
0.779220779220779, 0.916666666666667, 0.396825396825397, 0.876984126984127, 
0.961038961038961, 0.0649350649350649, 0.134920634920635, 0.285714285714286, 
0.948412698412698, 0.55952380952381, 0.904761904761905, 0.337662337662338, 
0.233766233766234, 0.785714285714286, 0.0198412698412698, 0.698412698412698, 
0.956349206349206, 0.884920634920635, 0.579365079365079), ACTIVIDAD = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ZPIE", 
"ecd", "ACTIVIDAD"), row.names = c(166L, 258L, 202L, 158L, 207L, 
319L, 288L, 98L, 329L, 46L, 15L, 1L, 277L, 272L, 92L, 33L, 23L, 
201L, 194L, 197L), class = "data.frame")
```

This the code that I wrote to get the plot:

```
a <- ggplot(intactos,aes(x = ZPIE, y = ecd))+  
     geom_line(aes(group = ACTIVIDAD,colour = ACTIVIDAD,linetype=ACTIVIDAD),size = 1,colour="black")+
     xlab("Altitud m") +
     ylab("Distribucion Acumulada (%)")+
     scale_x_continuous(limits=c(3500,5000),breaks=c(3500,3750,4000,4250,4500,4750,5000))+
     geom_vline(aes(xintercept=4000),linetype="dashed",size = 1)+
     geom_text(aes(4050,.85,label = "0°C MAAT isoterma")
                  ,vjust=0,
                  ,fontface= 'plain'
                  ,colour='black'
                  ,size=5)+
  theme(  plot.background  = element_rect(fill="white")
         ,panel.background = element_rect(fill='white')
         ,panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey', linetype = 'dashed')
         ,panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'white', linetype = 'dashed')
         ,panel.border = element_blank()
         ,axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black')
         ,axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black")
         ,axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")
         ,panel.grid.major =element_line(colour = 'grey', linetype = 'dashed')
         ,legend.key=element_rect(fill="white",colour="white"),legend.position=c(0.25,0.7))


a +    coord_flip()
```

Here is the plot that I tried to create 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11320858/plot_zoom_png2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I was a little confused as to how things work round here when I joined not so long ago. The idea is to supply a reproducible example with code when you ask a question. You've supplied some code, which is great, but we can't see the structure of your data. So please use `dput(head(intactos, 20))` and paste the result into your question. If the data is proprietary then make "fake" data that mimics the structure of your real data. Read [this useful post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for help.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a sample data frame

Comment: Thanks for that. However, the graphic you link to shows two data series and the data frame only seems to hold one. I'm guessing that you left out the grouping variable from the data frame. Is that what `ACTIVIDAD` refers to in your code? If you can give (or generate) data for both series we should be able to help.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just added the variable (ACTIVIDAD) that I left out from the data.frame. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you help Slowlearner. I just fixed the code with your commentaries. I could fix the code using `melt()` function at the beginning and `scale_linetype_maunual` into the code. **Here is the new code.**

```
library(reshape)

intactos2 <- melt(intactos, id.var = c("ecd","ACTIVIDAD"))

a <- ggplot(intactos2,aes(y = value,  x= ecd,group=ACTIVIDAD))+  
     geom_line(aes(colour = ACTIVIDAD,linetype=ACTIVIDAD),colour='black',size=0.5)+
     scale_linetype_manual("Glaciares rocosos",
                            breaks=c("1","2"), 
                            values=c("solid","dashed"),
                            labels = c("Activos", "Inactivos"))+
     ylab("Altitud m") +
     xlab("Distribucion Acumulada (%)\n")+
     scale_y_continuous(limits=c(3500,5000),
                        breaks=c(3500,3750,4000,4250,4500,4750,5000))+
     scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.00, 1.00),
                        breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1),
                        labels=seq(0,100,10))+
  theme(  plot.background  = element_rect(fill="white")
         ,panel.background = element_rect(fill='white')
         ,panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey', linetype = 'dotted',size=0.5)
         ,panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'white', linetype = 'dashed')
         ,panel.border = element_blank()
         ,axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black')
         ,axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black")
         ,axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")
         ,panel.grid.major =element_line(colour = 'grey', linetype = 'dashed')
         ,legend.key=element_rect(fill="white",colour="white"),legend.position=c(0.3,0.8))+
          geom_hline(aes(yintercept=4000),linetype="solid",size = 0.5)
a

a   +    annotate("text",label="0°C MAAT isoterma",x=0.8,y=4050,size=4)
```

Here the plot that I finally got! https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11320858/plot3.png

Comment: Glad to hear that. If my answer led you to resolve the question, you might consider marking it as correct (by clicking on the checkmark to the left of my answer) or by upvoting it (by clicking on the up button next to the answer). In this way those who answer questions get recognition and are motivated to keep doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's hard to tell given the limited data you were able to share but I think you probably want something like the below. Have a tinker and see if it works for you.

[image: screenshot]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

intactos <-
    structure(list(ZPIE = c(4129L, 4547L, 4448L, 4181L, 4439L, 4113L,3893L, 4275L, 4385L, 4037L), ecd = c(0.126984126984127, 0.849206349206349,0.706349206349206, 0.222222222222222, 0.69047619047619, 0.233766233766234,0.038961038961039, 0.420634920634921, 0.626984126984127, 0.0238095238095238)), .Names = c("ZPIE", "ecd"), row.names = c(79L, 200L, 132L, 102L, 219L,272L, 278L, 84L, 17L, 133L), class = "data.frame")

intactos$ACTIVIDAD <- "one"
intactos$ACTIVIDAD[6:10] <- "two"

library(reshape)
intactos.m <- melt(intactos, id.var = c("ecd", "ACTIVIDAD"))

ggplot(data = intactos.m, aes(y = value, x = ecd, group = ACTIVIDAD)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = ACTIVIDAD)) +
    ylab("Altitud m") +
    xlab("Distribucion Acumulada (%)\n") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(3500,5000),
                       breaks = c(3500,3750,4000,4250,4500,4750,5000))+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.1),
                       breaks = seq(0, 2, 0.1)) +
    scale_colour_manual("Legend", labels = c("line one", "line two"),
                        values = c("blue", "red")) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 4000),linetype = "dashed", size = 1)+
    geom_text(data = intactos[1, ], aes(y = 4050, x = 0.85),
               label = "0°C MAAT isoterma", vjust = 0, fontface = 'plain',
               colour = 'black', size=5) +
    theme()
```